# php.ini resetting on MAMP server restart

Tags: mamp, php

I am trying to change `display_errors = Off` to `display_errors = On` in my php.ini. I ran phpinfo() and verified the Loaded Configuration File (it is located here: /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini).

Everytime I edit the `display_errors` value of this php.ini file and restart my MAMP server, the php.ini file seems to reset. If I open the php.ini file again after restarting MAMP it shows `display_errors = Off`.

Why might MAMP be resetting the php.ini file?

note - I'm using MAMP Pro if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The way I have done it was to change the template that MAMP Pro replaces your php.ini file with. In my case the ini file that PHP was loading was found at

```
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini
```

but everytime I changed it, MAMP Pro wrote over it with its own version. To change what I wanted to change in the php.ini file, I simply found the template:

```
/Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources/php5.4.4.ini
```

(PHP 5.4.4 is the version i'm using) and then I changed what I needed to change :D Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a perfect solution working perfectly!

Comment: After doing the above I had to run Edit>Edit Templates>Reset All Templates and then it worked

Answer (score 3):

You can set php.ini values with the template editor in Mamp Pro.

File -> Edit Template -> PHP (php.ini)

Select the same version your instance is running.

When you save the template Mamp will overwrite the php.ini file used for your instance and restart Apache.

[image: Edit PHP INI WITH MAMP TEMPLATE EDITOR]

Comment: This is a tremendously helpful response. There are many questions with good solutions for editing regular MAMP, but this is the only workable process for updating a MAMP PRO configuration.

Comment: This is the only working solution , but mamp pro is not free for forever.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. MAMP Pro works differently than regular MAMP. With regular MAMP you would edit the appropriate php.ini file directly. With MAMP Pro however you have to use the MAMP Pro interface to control the php.ini settings. MAMP Pro recreates the php.ini file each time the server starts based on these settings.

In my case, to display server errors I had to open the MAMP Pro interface. Click on the `Server` tab. Click on the `PHP` tab. Check the `Display startup errors` checkbox. Check the `All errors and warnings` checkbox. Check the `Display` checkbox. Apply the changes and restart the server.